# How do I force Mathematica to include user defined functions in Simplify and FullSimplify?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplify

Let's say I have a relation r^2 = x^2 + y^2. Now suppose after a calculation i get a complicated output of x and y, but which could in theory be simplified a lot by using the above relation. How do I tell Mathematica to do that?

I'm referring to situations where replacement rules x^2+y^2 -> r^2 and using Simplify/FullSimplify with Assumptions won't work, e.g. if the output is x/y + y/x = (x^2+y^2)/(xy) = r^2/(xy).

Simplification works really well with built in functions but not with user defined functions! So essentially I would like my functions to be treated like the built in functions!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) if you have questions about the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [TransformationFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunctions.html).

```
f = # /. x^2 + y^2 -> r^2 &;

Simplify[x/y + y/x, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, f}]

(* Out=  r^2/(x y)  *)
```

Comment: @Super, a word of caution about `TransformationFunctions`, the enable you to right replacement rules that violate mathematical rules. So, consider the transformation carefully before you use it.

Comment: @rcollyer Or impose trivial assumptions that disable a whole family of solutions (denominator NEQ 0 is the classical example)

Answer (score 2):

In the example you give

```
(x/y + y/x // Together) /. {x^2 + y^2 -> r^2}

==> r^2/(x y)
```

works. But I've learned that in many occasions replacements like this don't work. A tip I once got was to replace this replacement with one which has a more simpler LHS like: `x^2 -> r^2-y^2` (or even `x->Sqrt[r^2-y^2]` if you know that the values of x and y allow this).

Comment: I think the Mma box should come with a big red surgeon general's warning: "Don't expect this software to write formulas like you do". Much frustration could be avoided.

Comment: @Sjeord, that works precisely because `Together` makes the numerator `x^2 + y^2` without any other terms present. If they're were other terms present, the likelihood of it working goes down quite a bit. Truthfully, I don't know if the `TransformationFunction` given by Mr. Wizard would work in that case.